# Upgraded exp-resso Store from 1.6x to 2.5.1 Check Out Error

Tags: expresso-store

I upgraded exp-resso Store from 1.6 to 2.5.1. Store worked fine on 1.6 but I needed to upgrade EE to 2.10.3 Now I get the checkout error "This transaction cannot be accepted." I checked with AuthorizeNet and the API Login ID and the Transaction Key are fine. It was my understanding that I needed to change/add the payment_method in checkout3.html file.

```
Original code in checkout3.html

<select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
<option value=""></option>
{payment_method_options}
</select>

changed to this:
<select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
<option value="AuthorizeNet_AIM" selected>Credit Card</option>
</select>
```

I still get the error “This transaction cannot be accepted."

I have looked through support docs and I still can’t figure out what to do. Any suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in all new templates files and also generated a new transaction key (3rd time) at AuthorizeNet and it works